Pact Contract Testing - Let the test fail when misses required enum member
We have a case that a consumer is very strict about the current enum members that it consumes. So the consumer expects to only receive the enum members and is quite lose to have new enum members.
enum ProductTypes {
   Car, //required by consumer
   Plane, //required by consumer
   Train //new enum member
} // passes the contract test

enum ProductTypes {
   //car was removed by the provider
   Plane
} // should fail the contract test

In the contract tests we want to let the provider fail, when the scenarios misses an required enum member, but should lose when adding a new enum member.
Currently I dont see any Matcher being capable of doing that.
Can that be fixed with "Plugins" ?
Is there an other way to cover that in the contract tests?
I had a look onto Regex, but this doesnt fit the criteria.


In the contract tests we want to let the provider fail, when the scenarios misses an required enum member, but should lose when adding a new enum member.

That's how contract tests are designed to work. It will only fail if the consumer enforces a too-strict contract on the provider (see this guide on the topic of good consumer assertions).
enum ProductTypes {
   //car was removed by the provider
   Plane
} // should fail the contract test

To enforce this failure, you need to have separate tests for each scenario (i.e. one for each required enum) - obviously you want to make sure this is a useful test. If a provider removes an enum and this doesn't break consumers, this is not something you should enforce into the contract. Ideally, you want to be able to add/remove enums that don't break consumers.
